# What is the difference between bemerklich vs. bemerkbar?

Tags: difference, word-choice

The terms *bemerklich* and *bemerkbar* are certainly very close in meaning. I could not think of a situation where only one of them, but not the other, would be applicable. Are there any?

It also seems this is a particularity of these two words and does not generalize to many other x-*lich* / x-*bar* pairs, or does it?

**Edit:** Several commenters pointed out that the term *bemerklich* is unusual. Google finds 260k hits for the term, and [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bemerklich%2Cbemerkbar&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20) shows it as similarly common as *bemerkbar* until around 1870, then declining. [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/german-english/bemerklich.html) also demarks it as veraltet. It seems the term is not in common use anymore; I probably picked it up from old literature and according set expressions. (Ich bin Muttersprachler.)

Comment: *bemerklich* is at least obsolescent. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bemerkbar%2Cbemerklich&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbemerkbar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbemerklich%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I'm quite certain that I've gone through half my lifespan without ever coming across the word *bemerklich* even once.

Comment: *merklich* already states the meaning (and is not on the brink of extinction), the prefix *be-* can easily be disposed.

Comment: The Duden doesn't have "bemerklich". The usual word is "merklich", as already noted by guidot.

Comment: I was thinking of _Diese Sache hat sich bemerklich gemacht_. I heard that rather often.

Comment: Where did you hear that?

Comment: Just for information: *Duden Deutsches Universalwörterbuch A-Z, 2nd edition, 1989*, with 1816 pages, does not have *bemerklich* either. Doesn't mean it is not in use anyway, but I also wonder where you found that. Perhaps it is a spontaneous creation based on the more common *unbemerklich*.

Comment: The latter, unlike the form, is actually a word in current use.

Comment: It seems _bemerklich_ is indeed old fashioned, I added a short note regarding that.

Answer (score 1):

First, “bemerken” means “to notice”.

The *-bar* suffix has the connotations of *-ful*. E.g. wunderbar (wonderful), dankbar (grateful) that are only positive.

The *-lich* suffix has more of the connotations of *-able*. So bemerklich would mean “noticeable”. There is no “danklich” in German, but “wunderlich” loosely translates to “causing wonder," which could be either good or bad, not necessarily “wonderful”.

There is no equivalent English translation of bemerkbar like “noticeful”, so bemerkbar also translates to “noticeable”, but more emphatically and only positively.

“Bemerklich” could have positive *or* negative connotations.

> Seine Krawatte ist krumm; das ist bemerklich (not bemerkbar).
>   His tie is crooked. That is noticeable.

**Addition:** A commenter noted that the last passage above is correct, but not "standard" German, and was posed as an "example."

Comment: Totally right but in my eyes people wouldn’t use words like _bemerklich_.  A common paraphrase would be: “Seine Krawatte ist krumm. Das ist ziemlich auffällig”

Comment: @Devon: OK, added a line to that effect. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I find the given connotations somewhat arbitrary. In *bemerkbar* as well as in *machbar* the *bar* translates clearly to the same *-able* you assigned to the *-lich* suffix. I also can't confirm the negative connotation for *bemerklich* after a short glance over the [example findings](http://www.zeno.org/Zeno/0/Suche?&q=bemerklich&s=40) from zeno.org.

Comment: @guidot: I was using the analogy between wunderlich and wunderbar. Wunderbar means "wonderful" in a good sense. Wunderlich means inspiring wonder in a good or bad sense. Therefore, I conclude that bemerklich means "attracting" notice" as a "two way" term, and bemerkbar as attracting "favorable" notice. But Devon pointed out that "bemerklich" is only technically correct, and not in general use, which I incorporated into my post.

Comment: I'd say it's the other way round. *-bar* typically matches *-able* and *-lich* roughly matches *-ful*. Note that *wunderbar* is an atypical example. If I remember correctly, it used to mean *seltsam*, in the sense that it's possible to "sich wundern" (thus placing this in the *-able* group again).